# python file split by columns ignoring some characters

Tags: python, file, split

I have the following file.

```
andrew  *administrator
matt  *worker
tim  *teacher
jack  *worker
```

How can i split into two files, in the first one: the name, second one the activity ignoring the * character.

Comment: Does the space between string and asterisk is the same to all row?

Comment: Yes, is the same to all rows

Comment: What code have you written yourself to try solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*You can read the original `file.txt` line by line and then split that line using `string.split("*")` method and then write back parts of each splitted line into separate files `file1.txt` and `file2.txt`.*

**Try this:**

```
with open("file.txt", "r") as f, open("file1.txt", "w") as file1, open("file2.txt", "w") as file2:
    for line in f:
        parts = line.split("*")
        file1.write(f"{parts[0].strip()}\n") # --> write name
        file2.write(f"{parts[1].strip()}\n") # --> write activity
```